# any ways to rename auto complete parameters in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm studying SQLiteOpenHelper in Android Studio.

There is a method
`public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}` that I have to override and the second and third parameters of this method are auto completed like this below.

`onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1)`

It's not a big problem but I would like the parameters to be completed with their original names like the one I mentioned.

The Android Studio auto complete seems to names the int parameters with just "i", but I don't really like it.

Are there any ways to change this?

Comment: perfect answers, thank you so much